# How to turn off Android Device Manager on the web

Tags: security, android-device-manager

My phone got stolen yesterday. I have never downloaded Android Device Manager or enabled it on my phone but for some reason, when I go onto the ADM web page, it could track my phone (up until a day before it was stolen).

So in a panic, I first changed my Google password to stop the thief from using my account, then I locked the phone using Android Device  Manager and then I clicked the 'Erase' command so that he could not get hold of sensitive information. Now the phone is off and I have installed several tracking apps on PlayStore since then but they are yet to be activated since it is still off. However, I have just learned that once it is switched on, that 'Erase' command will be executed and I can longer track my phone :( I read a question elsewhere where someone said he had lost his phone and requested the 'Erase' command but due to the phone being off, the command had not yet been executed. He then found the phone so in order to prevent the command from being executed, he turned off ADM and when he switched it on, the command was not executed. He never explained how he did this however. What I would like to know is how to I turn off ADM on the web. I don't seem to have the 'Options' box that is described in the instructions below:

> You can instead use a Web browser and Google’s Android Device Manager
>   page. After signing in to your Google account, you’ll see a Google
>   Maps page with an options box in the top-left corner. All of the
>   compatible Android devices registered to your Google account will
>   appear in a drop-down menu within that box.

Answer (score 1):

The `Options` box gives you a list of devices linked with your google account to select from. If you just had only one device, there might not be any drop-down `Options` box. You should be able to view/manage the devices by going to 
https://play.google.com/settings

[image]

Some more info that might help: ([Source](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3265955?hl=en) )

**Switch Android Device Manager on or off**

Before you can use Android Device Manager, you need to make sure it's turned on and that your device is associated with your Google Account. If you have a tablet with more than one user, only the tablet owner can control this setting.

1. Find Google Settings in one of these places (depending on your device):

   - A separate app called **Google Settings**
   - In your main **Settings app**, scroll down and touch **Google**
2. Touch **Security**.
3. Under "Android Device Manager," switch **Remotely locate this device** and **Allow remote lock and factory reset** on or off.

Comment: Thank you. I have managed to find the device on the web using that link. However, it still does not allow me to turn Android Device Manager on or off in the device. I am trying to switch ADM off so that I can switch it on again a few days later when the thieves have switched the phone on so that I may be able to remotely lock it without that Erase command having been carried out.